# Why doesn't my textbox accept decimal point?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have applied this but when I put decimal point `.`. , the textbox doesn't accept.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDetAmount" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
     OnTextChanged="OntxtDetAmountChanged"  
     style="width: 50%;" AutoComplete="off" 
     onkeydown = "return (!(event.keyCode>=65) && event.keyCode!=32);">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a problem here: `!(event.keyCode>=65)` '.' keyCode is 190 And it is greater than 65. Therefore it does not work

**UPDATE**

```
onkeydown = "return ((event.keyCode != 186) && (event.keyCode != 32) && (event.keyCode != 188));"
```

Comment: so what shall i do?

Comment: event.keyCode != 65, if you want to prevent space and 'a' typed

Comment: See https://keycode.info/ for more info on keyCodes

Comment: let me check this

Comment: What buttons do you want not typed?

Comment: space, comma, colon shall not be inserted

Comment: 186 is keyCode for semicolon / colon, 188 for comma, 32 for space

Comment: let me try this one